# How can I use out from Jquery as variable for php Query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this code below which display the item that has been clicked using Jquery

```
<html>
<head>

    <?php include('config/js.php');?>

</head>
<body>
                                    <div id="target">
                                        <h4>Hydraulics</h4>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">Bikes</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Utes</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">cars</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">Trucks</a></li>

                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
<body>
    <script>
       $('#target li').click(function() {
            var text = $(this).text();
            alert('Text is ' + text);
        });
    </script>

 </html>
```

Is there a way I can use this output as a variable for php query something like below so that I can use '$var' instead of 'Trucks';

```
<?php
             $q = "SELECT subgroup FROM jqm_categories WHERE name = 'Trucks' ";
             $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

             While($list = mysqli_fetch_assoc($r)) {?>

         <a href="#" class="catag"><?php echo $list['subgroup'].'<br/>';?></a>

                <?php } ?>
```

Comment: What output do you want to use?

Comment: Do you ask for a way how to transfer the parameter value for "hydraulics" subgroups to the php script (the 2nd one) that generates a list of these items? Do you use JQuery AJAX to call the php script?

Comment: Yeah you need an ajax call sending the 'text' to the php ajax page, then it's how you want to handle that. You could either a) pass a json array back and get javascript to create the function (this might be best - separate out the code a little) b) Get the ajax page to create the a tag and then javascript will just dump it whereever.

Answer (score 0):

In the javascript put

```
$.get("http://example.com/foo.php?name=" + text);
```

instead of the alert and in the php use:

```
mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name'])
```

instead of Trucks.

Comment: Where should the `$.get()` go? And the `$_GET`? That last effort might help newcomers :)